# How to flag id's by a condition?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I want to create a column that flags an id it has a straight order process. i.e. id’s which don’t have `order_status` *pending* or *info_required*.

e.g. id `a` has *pending*, so `is_straight` will be false. `b` has no pending or info_required, so it should be true.
[image]

Here is the example data:

```
    WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'a' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-11-02 15:04:07'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-11-03 13:23:34'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' AS id, 'pending' AS status, '2021-11-07 04:04:46'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' AS id, 'successful' AS status, '2021-11-07 13:25:05'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-11-11 16:19:07'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' AS id, 'successful' AS status, '2021-11-13 17:57:55'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-11-15 01:09:23'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' AS id, 'info_required' AS status, '2021-11-17 11:06:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' AS id, 'successful' AS status, '2021-11-21 23:35:46'::timestamp AS created_at
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using windowed [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html):

```
SELECT *,
   COUNT_IF(order_status IN ('pending', 'info_required')) OVER(PARTITION BY id) = 0 
            AS is_straight
FROM t1;
```

Output:

[image]